# Need a python module for stemming of text documents

Tags: python, module, preprocessor, nlp, stemming

I need a good  python module for stemming text documents in the pre-processing stage.

I found this one

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStemmer/1.0.1

but i cannot find the documentation int the link provided.

I anyone knows where to find the documentation or any other good stemming algorithm please help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may want to try [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org)

```
>>> from nltk import PorterStemmer
>>> PorterStemmer().stem('complications')
```

Comment: Wasn't the PorterStemmer developed in the 1980s?  Surely there is a more advanced option?

Comment: You are correct that there are other stemmers.  From the preview of the [Natural Language Processing with Python section on stemmers](http://www.nltk.org/book3/ch03.html#stemmers) they do a simple comparison of Lancaster to Porter and then state "Stemming is not a well-defined process, and we typically pick the stemmer that best suits the application we have in mind. The Porter Stemmer is a good choice if you are indexing some texts and want to support search using alternative forms of words."

Answer (score 8):

All these stemmers that have been discussed here are algorithmic stemmer,hence they can always produce unexpected results such as

```
In [3]: from nltk.stem.porter import *

In [4]: stemmer = PorterStemmer()

In [5]: stemmer.stem('identified')
Out[5]: u'identifi'

In [6]: stemmer.stem('nonsensical')
Out[6]: u'nonsens'
```

To correctly get the root words one need a dictionary based stemmer such as Hunspell Stemmer.Here is a python implementation of it in the following [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hunspell). Example code is here

```
>>> import hunspell
>>> hobj = hunspell.HunSpell('/usr/share/myspell/en_US.dic', '/usr/share/myspell/en_US.aff')
>>> hobj.spell('spookie')
False
>>> hobj.suggest('spookie')
['spookier', 'spookiness', 'spooky', 'spook', 'spoonbill']
>>> hobj.spell('spooky')
True
>>> hobj.analyze('linked')
[' st:link fl:D']
>>> hobj.stem('linked')
['link']
```

Comment: -1: The object of stemmers is not to find the root word (or lemmatization, which nltk also has a module for), but rather find a shortened version of the word that other inflections would also shorten to. It doesn't matter if the stemmer does not find the root word; as long as `stem('nonsense') == stem('nonsensical') != stem('bananas')`, it's fine.

Answer (score 7):

Python stemming module has implementations of various stemming algorithms like Porter, Porter2, Paice-Husk, and Lovins.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stemming/1.0

```
    >> from stemming.porter2 import stem
    >> stem("factionally")
    faction
```

Comment: Be aware that this is a pure python implementation and performs slower at scale than things like PyStemmer which are wrappers for a fast C implementation

Answer (score 3):

The [`gensim` package](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) for topic modelling comes with a Porter Stemmer algorithm:

```
>>> from gensim import parsing
>>> gensim.parsing.stem_text("trying writing nonsense")
'try write nonsens'
```

The PorterStemmer is the only stemming option implemented in `gensim`.

An a side note: I can imagine (without further references) that most text-mining-related modules have their own implementations for simple pre-processing procedures like Porter's stemming, white-space removal and stop-word removal.

Answer (score 1):

PyStemmer is a Python interface to the Snowball stemming library.

Documentation can be found here:
https://github.com/snowballstem/pystemmer/blob/master/docs/quickstart.txt
https://github.com/snowballstem/pystemmer/blob/master/docs/quickstart_python3.txt