# Built-in Porter Stemmer in java opennlp toolkit

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, porter-stemmer

Like there are built in Stemmers like porter Stemmer in python nltk (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10369407/3096792 ), I want to know if there is any built-in Porter Stemmer in java apache opennlp though there is an interface under this package [opennlp.tools.stemmer.Stemmer]. Since I dont know or need to know the algorithm behind stemming as of now,I need a standard package under apache opennlp toolkit. If not present, whats the alternative in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache Lucene Snowball Library [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/lucene-snowball/lucene-snowball-3.0.2.jar.zip)

Just put this jar file inside your build path and use it

```
PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
stemmer.setCurrent(input); //set string you need to stem
stemmer.stem();  //stem the word
stemmer.getCurrent();//get the stemmed word
```

Comment: I downloaded java version from that link, which contains a bunch of java files ( not jar ) , so how can I include them in my build path . Also there is no class called PorterStemmer  , I am confused which jar file are you talking about @Exbury

Comment: sry download Apache lucene http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/lucene-snowball/lucene-snowball-3.0.2.jar.zip

Comment: There is no such class in the provide jar. Please verify and let us know ?